# Завершение цикла разбора блокирующей очереди (PoisingPill)

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть блокирующая очередь, которая содержит в себе таски для выполнения:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);
private final AtomicInteger isPoisingPill = new AtomicInteger(2); //two producers
```

Также есть потребитель:

```
while (isPoisingPill.get() != 0) {
     processExecutor.submit(this.kpiData.take()));
}
```

Каждый поставщик, когда завершает работу, делает: `isPoisingPill.decrementAndGet();`

Но работает не во всех случаях. Бывают моменты, когда мы зашли в цикл, поставщик выставил пилюлю в `false`, и на этом программа зависла, т.к. операция `take()` ждет появления элемента в очереди, а его нет, т.к. поставщики закончили работу.  Получается, пилюлю нужно ложить непосредственно в очередь, и в цикле уже проверять на равенство. Но что мне туда ложить, если очередь содержит только Runnable объекты?

Также возникает ситуация, когда у меня много поставщиков. Нужно дождаться их завершения.